# Add type restrictions to multiple type parameters?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have an Extension Method

```
public static bool Between<T1, T2>(this T1 Foo, T2 bar) where T1: IComparable
{
     //Body
}
```

How to restrict my EM so that both T1: IComparable and T2: IConvertible

I tried

```
T1: IComparable, T2: IConvertible
```

but gives error. Then how to write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 where T1: IComparable where T2: IConvertible
```

For more information on Constraints on Type Parameters, look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx